# save FK value referencing a lookup table

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework

I have 2 tables:

User (Id, Title_Value **FK**)

Title (Value **PK**, Text) - This is a lookup table with fixed values (Mr, Ms, ...)

then I have a form with the title bounded to a dropdown.

what is the syntax to save the Title_value in the database?

I tried this with no luck (the dropdown is passing the correct value):

```
User user = new User();
user.Title.Value = Dropdown_Title.SelectedValue;
```

the error I get is the usual Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like

```
Title title = dataContext.Titles.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Value==Dropdown_Title.SelectedValue);
User user = new User();
user.Title = title;
```

Comment: I get this error when I save: "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

Comment: Sounds like you are using multiple ObjectContexts.  The title that you looked up needs to come from the same ObjectContext that you will be using to update the new user.